# where are the query ressults written to during runtime

Tags: ssms

I installed SSMS on my windows 10 laptop for school and while on break my mates thought it would be fun to try and crash it, they did this by executing a cartesian product of the database;

```
select * from CAMPAIGN, COUNTRY, INVENTORY_LEVELS, ORDER_DETAILS,
ORDER_HEADER, ORDER_METHOD, PRODUCT, PRODUCT_FORECAST, PRODUCT_LINE,
PRODUCT_TYPE, PROMOTION, RETAILER, RETAILER_SITE, RETAILER_TYPE,
RETURN_REASON, RETURNED_ITEM, SALES_BRANCH, SALES_STAFF, SALES_TARGET
```

As i thought it would be fun to see how long it would take my pc to come up with an answer i left it running.

33 million rows (and about 20 minutes) later it stopped with the message "insufficient disk space available" and after forcing SSMS to close I checked my files only to see that my C:\ disk had 0 bytes left, after opening SSMS again it asked if i wanted to open the last recovered version or if i wanted to delete it, naturally i clicked delete but it only gave me back 4 GB on my c:\, which previously had around 32GB free.

so my question; where is the output saved on my pc? i've been looking for over an hour and i can't seem to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21895/system-disk-run-out-of-space-when-running-heavy-sql-queries-on-sql-server-2012

found it a couple of secconds after posting this, so quick answer:

```
C:\Users\Vecro\AppData\Local\Temp
```

it turned out to be a 31.7 million kb file [see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydiQO.png)

i guess i learned my lesson to always, ALWAYS lock your PC when you leave it with your friends